# MVC3 Controller not recongnising base controller with Ninject dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, nlog, petapoco

I've hooked up Ninject (correctly) to bind NLog. Here is my RegisterService method in my NinjectMVC3.cs

```
kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<NLogger>();
```

I'm trying to port over to PetaPoco and have created a base controller here:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected PetaPoco.Database _database;
    protected ILogger _logger;
    protected MemberRepository _members;

    public BaseController(ILogger logger)
    {
        _database = new PetaPoco.Database("TalentSiteConnection");
        _members = new MemberRepository(_database);
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

When I inherit my base controller like so:

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestViewModel model = new TestViewModel();
        model.Member = _members.Single<Member>(2579);
        return View("Index", model);
    }

}
```

and try to run a build I'm getting a

> 'BaseController' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

What am I doing wrong? I thought Ninject would resolve the dependency on the constructor?

.

Comment: Are you using custom controller factory or Ninject MVC extension? http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/using_ninject_in_asp_net_mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestController needs that ctor...

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public TestController(ILogger logger) : base(logger) {}
```

...this has nothing to do with NInject. If you added a parameterless ctor to BaseController and left your TestController as is, you wouldn't get the logger injection.